# Identify a data object using a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using VueJS. Let's say I have some data as follows:

```
data () {
 return {
   status: {
     a: false,
     b: false,
     c: false
   }
}
```

Now in a method, I can manipulate the data as follows:

```
method: {
  changeStatus: {
    this.status.b = true
  }
}
```

However, my requirement is that I have a variable which contains information about which status needs to change. For example:

```
let target = c
```

So, in my method, I want to change the status of c, i.e., `this.status.c = true`. My question is how can I use a variable (`target`) to target the correct data in my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bracket notation: `this.status['c']` instead of dot notation: `this.status.c`

You can then replace the literal property name string `'c'` with a variable.  For example

```
method: {
    changeStatus: function(target, value){
        this.status[target] = value;
    }
}
```